# Scrapy - "scrapy crawl" catches exceptions internally and hides them from Jenkins' "catch" clause

Tags: python, jenkins, scrapy

I'm running `scrapy` through Jenkins on a daily basis, and I want exceptions to be sent to me in emails.

This is an example spider:

```
class ExceptionTestSpider(Spider):
    name = 'exception_test'

    start_urls = ['http://google.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        raise Exception
```

This is the `.Jenkinsfile`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
try {
    node ('jenkins-small-py3.6'){
        ...
        stage('Execute Spider') {
            cd ...
            /usr/local/bin/scrapy crawl exception_test
        }
    }
} catch (exc) {
    echo "Caught: ${exc}"
    mail subject: "...",
            body: "The spider is failing",
              to: "...",
            from: "..."

    /* Rethrow to fail the Pipeline properly */
    throw exc
}
```

And this is the log:

```
...
INFO:scrapy.core.engine:Spider opened
2019-08-22 10:49:49 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
INFO:scrapy.extensions.logstats:Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-08-22 10:49:49 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
DEBUG:scrapy.extensions.telnet:Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
DEBUG:scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect:Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.google.com/> from <GET http://google.com>
DEBUG:scrapy.core.engine:Crawled (200) <GET http://www.google.com/> (referer: None)
ERROR:scrapy.core.scraper:Spider error processing <GET http://www.google.com/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "...", line ..., in parse
    raise Exception
Exception
2019-08-22 10:49:50 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.google.com/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "...", line ..., in parse
    raise Exception
Exception
INFO:scrapy.core.engine:Closing spider (finished)
2019-08-22 10:49:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
INFO:scrapy.statscollectors:Dumping Scrapy stats:
{
  ...
}
INFO:scrapy.core.engine:Spider closed (finished)
2019-08-22 10:49:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

And no mail is sent.
I believe Scrapy catches the exception internally, saves it to log later and then quits with no error.

How can I make Jenkins get the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that scrapy does not use a non-zero exit code when a **scrape** fails (src: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1231).

As said by the commenters in that issue, I suggest you to add a custom command (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/commands.html#custom-project-commands).